# Update a list item in moss2007

Tags: 2007, content-type

i have a list with Column name Reported By.It is a choice field.When adding a new item to the list the current user name also should be added to the Reported By column's field.It should be the first choice of column 'Reported By'. How can i do that? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the column "Reported By" to show the user who created the list item?

Is so, why not just use the default "Created By" field? You can always rename it if you want to "Reported By"

If you want some sort of concatenation, you can use calculated fields.

Stick with out of the box functionality before goign custom Event Receivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event receiver for your list and handle ItemAdding event - there you'll be able to modify field values.